# How do I make the bootstrap carousel controls appear on top of the images instead of next to them?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm using the carousel code provided by bootstrap and although it's working, the controls are taking up space to the right and left of the image instead of lying on top of them.

I'm a newbie so so far my attempt to fix this was to add

```
}
.left carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
}
.right carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
}
```

but it's not changing anything

Here is the full code, the controls are on the sides of the screen instead of on top of the images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Caroussel test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/uxcore.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/customer-comp.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var fqdn = "N1NWVPWEB066.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net";
redirectToLogin = function() {
    window.location.href = "https://" + fqdn + ":8443";
}
</script>   
    <style>
        .wrapper {
   position: relative;
}
.left.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
}
        }
.right.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="1-rs.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="2-rs.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="item">
      <img src="3-rs.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>

    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="position: absolute">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

++Update: I've tried to position the arrows on top of the images by adding position: absolute and top: 0 to carousel-control as suggested by @Swati and inspecting the element showed that those rule are being overridden by http://stockpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/less/carousel.less:96 and mydomain.com/:30
What does this mean? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Do u want the carousel navigations top of the image?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yup. Instead this is what it currently looks like: https://imgur.com/a/cegVeHq

Comment: https://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/IeKbA plz try this code..

Comment: @QuestionGenerator13 please include all of the relevant carousel code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I copy pasted your exact code yet for some reason this is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/YkNVyd9
The buttons don't do anything and I don't have any arrows.

I'm guessing I misplaced the js code? Excuse me as I'm pretty new at this. I basically just put it in the body at the end of the file as such:
<script>
$('#slideshow').carousel({
           interval: 5000
        });
  </script>
  </body>

Thanks!

Comment: @Zim I've updated the OP to include the whole code.

Comment: _“and inspecting the element showed that those rule are being overridden […] What does this mean?”_ - it means that you need to go read up on what _CSS Specificity_ means …

Comment: By what does this means I meant what :30 means... what rule is mydomain.com/:30

Answer (score 0):

Use this for remove the background.

```css
    .carousel-control.left {
        background-image: none!important;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
        background-image: none!important;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this screenshot to see what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/cegVeHq
I basically want those navigation elements to be on top.
The code you provided did not have any effect sadly

Comment: I'd like to move it on top of the image, I don't mind the background really.

Comment: You can use z-index for move image upper. For this it's not possible for this section because it's in the same function. So, you have to remove background image for your desire result. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Setting z-index to 0 did not have any effect either. However, when the website is not in full screen the arrows move and are in the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css into your code. Hope it will work into your question.

```
.carousel-control {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This removed the background color from behind the arrows (https://imgur.com/a/CwN63oY) but my question was how to move the white navigation arrows to the top of the pictures

Comment: U just add .carousel-control{ position: absolute ; top:0}.

Comment: I tried that but when I inspect the element in Chrome, there's a line running through these two properties (https://imgur.com/a/R0ZC5K3). Does that mean that something is overriding these settings and that's why it's having no effect?

Comment: so I looked into it and top: 0 is being overridden by http://stockpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/less/carousel.less:96 as well as (index):30